# Abelianization of algebra vs center of algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra ($k$ is a field). The commutator $[A,A]$ is defined as the $k$-vector subspace spanned by $xy-yx$ across $x,y \in A$. The center $Z(A)$ is defined as the set of $a \in A$ for which $ax=xa$ for all $x \in A$.

Question: What's the relation between $A/[A,A]$ and $Z(A)$?

I thought to ask this because for $A$ abelian, $A = \mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$, or $A = k[G]$ (with $G$ a group), the two are actually isomorphic (or at least both the same dimension). I'm curious if this is a coincidence or something deeper is going on.

Comment: Will, when $A$ is the non-commutative polynomials in $x,y$ over $k,$ then $A/[A,A]$ is just the standard commutative polynomials over $k,$ while $Z(A)\cong k.$ I don’t think you’ll find a useful general relationship.

Comment: How is $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$ associative?

Comment: Eep, my mistake. Just any algebra. Edited the question.